# VBA command for interpolating missing data in non-linear graph in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

So if you have a graph created in excel using vba, how do you tell it to interpolate any missing data point by averaging the previous / next data?  You can do easily by hand by following the following steps:

1 Select your graph
2 Open the "Select Data Source" window
3 clicking the "Hidden & Empty Cell" button
4 Select "Connect Data Point with Line" option under "Show Empty Cell As:"

But I need this done automatically in vba because the graph isn't by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I turn on the Macro Recorder and do the actions you said, I get:

```
ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, never thought of using the macro recorder to find command before!